# Why is growth on this Stromanthe streaked with green rather than purple undersides & some leaves have defects?

Tags: houseplants

This is a non-variegated Stromanthe. The new growth forming has green instead instead of purple undersides.
[image: Stromanthe]
Underside of leaves have green streaks instead of solid purple
[image: Stromanthe]
Underside of leaves have green streaks instead of solid purple
[image: Stromanthe]
Also, a few leaves have defects near base of leaf

Humidity: 54% to 60%

Temperature: 68F

Watering: when reaches 2 or 3 on the moisture meter (~7 days)

fertilizer: 0.6g 20-20-20 soluble every 4 months

pests: none detected